A complete metric space contains a convergent sequence or an infinite discrete subset
Theorem. Let $X$ be an infinite complete metric space. Then there is an injective convergent sequence in $X$ or there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and an infinite $\varepsilon$-discrete subset $A\subseteq X$. (I.e., a subset such that $(\forall x,y\in A) d(x,y)\ge\varepsilon$.)
I'll mention that we cannot omit the assumption that $X$ is complete. A counterexample would be, for example, $\{1/n; n>0, n\in\mathbb Z\}$ (with the usual Euclidean metric).
We require $X$ to be infinite - but finite metric spaces are discrete, so we're not losing anything interesting by this requirement.
This result (or perhaps exercise is a better word) was recently mentioned to me with the suggestion that it is a nice application of the infinite version of  Ramsey's theorem. I have tried to prove it in this way and posted an answer below.
If there are some nice alternative proofs of this fact, I would be interested in them. And if there are some references to the literature where this result is mentioned, it would be nice to learn about them, too.

You can take a more simple minded approach: Since $X$ is infinite, there is an injection of $\Bbb N$ into it. If that sequence is not $\epsilon$-discrete for any $\epsilon$, then it has a Cauchy sub-sequence.

@PaulSinclair Not true: The sequence $2, 2\frac12,3,3\frac13,4,4\frac14,\cdots$ is not $\epsilon$-discrete, for any $\epsilon$, but has no Cauchy sub-sequence.

The claim in the question can be shown using  the infinite version of Ramsey theorem. I.e., we are using the following fact: If $A$ is an infinite sets and all 2-element subsets of $A$ are colored either blue or red, there is an infinite monochromatic subset. (In the other words, if we color the edges of a complete graph with infinitely many vertices by two colors, there is an infinite set of vertices such that the edges between them have the same color.)
Basic idea. If we fix some $\varepsilon>0$, we can color pairs of points of $X$ in such way, that $\{x,y\}$ is blue if $d(x,y)<\varepsilon$ and red if $d(x,y)\ge\varepsilon$. If there is an infinite red subset, we have an infinite $\varepsilon$-discrete set.
Otherwise we have an infinite set of points that are $\varepsilon$-close to each other. We can now work only with this set of points. We can choose a smaller distance, for example $\varepsilon/2$, and repeat the same argument. Either we get a discrete set  at some step - or we can use this approach to inductively construct a Cauchy sequence.
Proof of the theorem formulated in the question.  Suppose that there is no $\varepsilon>0$ such that there is an infinite $\varepsilon$-discrete set in $X$.
Let us denote $\varepsilon_n=\frac1{2^n}$. Inductively we choose $A_n\subseteq X$ and $x_n\in A_n$ such that $$(\forall x,y\in A_n) d(x,y)<\varepsilon_n$$ and, at the same time, $x_n\notin\{x_k; k<n\}$ and $A_k\subseteq A_l$ for $l<k$.
The base case and the inductive step are very similar, so maybe we can simply put $\varepsilon_0=\infty$, $A_0=X$ and choose arbitrary $x_0\in X$; to formulate both the base case and the inductive step at the same time.
Inductive step. Let us assume we already have $A_0,A_1,\dots,A_{n-1}$ and $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}$. Let us color the edges between the points of $A_{n-1}$ by two colors depending on whether $d(x,y)<\varepsilon_n$ or $d(x,y)\ge\varepsilon_n$. Ramsey's theorem then implies that there is some infinite subset $A_n\subseteq A_{n-1}$ such that $$(\forall x,y\in A_n) d(x,y)<\varepsilon_n.$$ (Recall that by our assumption there is no infinite $\varepsilon_n$-discrete subset.)
Now we simply choose some point $x_n\in A_n\setminus\{x_k; k<n\}$.
The above construction implies that for $k \ge n$ we have $x_k\in A_n$. Consequently, for $k,l \ge n$ we have $$d(x_k,x_l)<\varepsilon_n$$ and we get a Cauchy sequence. Since $X$ is complete, this sequence is convergent. And this construction also ensures that the sequence is injective. $\square$

I. With Ramsey's theorem. Ramsey's theorem says that, for any positive integer $r$, if the $r$-element subsets of an infinite set are colored with two colors, then there is an infinite subset whose $r$-element subsets are all the same color. We use the case $r=3$. Start with an injective sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots$ in $X$. Let each set $\{i,j,k\}\subset\mathbb N$, where $i\lt j\lt k$, be colored blue if $d(x_j,x_k)\lt\frac12d(x_i,x_j)$, red if $d(x_j,x_k)\ge\frac12d(x_i,x_j)$. Let $i_1\lt i_2\lt i_3\lt\cdots$ be an infinite subset of $\mathbb N$ with all $3$-element subsets the same color. If they are all blue, then $x_{i_1},x_{i_2},x_{i_3},\dots$ is a Cauchy sequence and therefore convergent. If they are all red, then the set $\{x_{i_2},x_{i_3},x_{i_4},\dots\}$ is an infinite $\varepsilon$-discrete set where $\varepsilon=\frac14d(x_{i_1},x_{i_2})\gt0$, since $2\lt m\lt n\implies d(x_{i_m},x_{i_n})\ge\frac12d(x_{i_2},x_{i_m})\ge\frac14d(x_{i_1},x_{i_2})=\varepsilon$.
II. Without Ramsey's theorem. We can use the fact that a metric space is compact iff it's complete and totally bounded. Given $\varepsilon\gt0$ let $X_\varepsilon$ be a maximal $\varepsilon$-discrete subset of $X$. If some $X_\varepsilon$ is infinite, we're done. If every $X_\varepsilon$ is finite, then $X$ is totally bounded and therefore compact. If every point were isolated, then $X$ would be finite. Since $X$ is infinite, $X$ has a non-isolated point, and there is an injective sequence converging to that point.
